# Python guessing game : IndexError: range object index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, index-error

I created a game wherein I select a number from 1 to 100, and the computer guesses it. However I get IndexError when i'm selecting numbers below 6. why is this happening?.

Here is my code :

```
print("Helllo user, select a number from 1-100 in your mind and i will try to guess it...")

list_nums = range(1,101)
counter = 0

while True :
    mid_element = list_nums[int(len(list_nums)/2)-1]
    print(" Is your selected number {}".format(mid_element))
    counter = counter + 1
    response = str(input("is it too high or too low..? : "))
    try:
        if response == "too low":
            list_nums = list_nums[int(len(list_nums)/2):int(len(list_nums))]
            mid_element = list_nums[int(len(list_nums)/2)]

        elif response == "too high":
            list_nums = list_nums[1:int(len(list_nums)/2)]
            mid_element = list_nums[int(len(list_nums)/2)]

        elif response == "correct":
            print("Perfect i finally guessed it. Your number is {}\n".format(mid_element))
            break
    except:
        print("Invalid entry..Try again")
        continue

print("\nI guessed it in {} attempts".format(counter))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change line

```
list_nums = list_nums[1: int(len(list_nums)/2)]
```

to:

```
list_nums = list_nums[0: int(len(list_nums)/2)]
```

Because, list index starts at zero.

Or:

```
list_nums = list_nums[: int(len(list_nums)/2)]
```

Because, Python knows list starts at zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It works. Its only my second week of coding. A silly mistake it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I went through your code and ran on my system. Every time your list size is reducing and at the end it becomes to 0. At that time when your code compute the line `mid_element = list_nums[int(len(list_nums)/2)-1]` the answer is -1 which is out of range.

I have traced the code, and the output are as follows:

`Helllo user, select a number from 1-100 in your mind and i will try to guess it...
Length of list_num:  100
 Is your selected number 50
is it too high or too low..? : too high
Length of list_num:  49
 Is your selected number 25
is it too high or too low..? : too high
Length of list_num:  23
 Is your selected number 13
is it too high or too low..? : too high
Length of list_num:  10
 Is your selected number 8
is it too high or too low..? : too high
Length of list_num:  4
 Is your selected number 6
is it too high or too low..? : too high
Length of list_num:  1
 Is your selected number 6
is it too high or too low..? : too high
Invalid entry..Try again
Length of list_num:  0`

So make the changes given in the above answer.